# Issue with Coordinates

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

Using Cord-ova to get device position I experience a weird behavior when trying to access position coordinates using the emulator (also deployed the code on my Galaxy S2 ... same issue).

```
 document.addEventListener( "deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady () {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
          var options = { timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: Infinity };
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationOnSuccess, locationOnSuccess, options);
       } else {
            alert("Geoloc does not exists");
       }
    }

    var locationOnSuccess = function (pos){
       alert('Latitude: '  + pos.coords.latitude);
    }
```

navigator.geolocation exists as it fires the alert
        This says latitude undefined and error I get is

```
11-13 08:44:05.296: D/CordovaLog(1861): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 55 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    11-13 08:44:05.296: E/Web Console(1861): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:55
```

I'm struggling for 1 day now and cannot find anybody having same issue, probably getting blind at looking for too long?
Anybody to help?

Many thanks, S.

Comment: What is in the line 55 in your index.html ?

Comment: onLocationError funciton declaration

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled this:

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

**also check if your device supports Geolocation**

Answer (score 1):

In PhoneGap's documentation the statement to get location updates is defined like the one below.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

So there are success and error cases. But you are calling the same method for both of the cases. So in the case that you don't have geo locations you cannot get the latitude and longitude values. That could cause the error. Instead of showing the error case in else statement, define an error function that shows this in the error case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change it to locationOnError

**navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationOnSuccess, locationOnError, options);**

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(coordinates);

function coordinates(p) {

        if (lastTrackedLat == null) {
            lastTrackedLat = p.coords.latitude;
        }

        if (lastTrackedLng == null) {
            lastTrackedLng = p.coords.longitude;
        }

        var lastTrackedLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lastTrackedLat,lastTrackedLng);

        var lat = p.coords.latitude;
        var lng = p.coords.longitude;

        var Latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); 
}
```

Comment: Yes sure, locationOnError I'm getting blind at struggling too much :-(
Now, I have a timeout message ... progressing

Comment: Yes. Now, the onLocationError function is fired and I've got a error.code=3 (Timeout)  Error.